# configure grid extra (groupon) with jenkins in order to run cucumber tests

Tags: jenkins, selenium-grid

I'm struggling with something for quite a while and can't find a solution,
I got a test project (cucumber, maven) I configure jenkins to pull the project from github, build and execute the code (selenium test script) on jenkins slave and that works perfect, I added few more slave, tagged them and I'm able to execute the same job parallel(the same test cases on different machines)

my next step is to use grid extra (https://github.com/groupon/Selenium-Grid-Extras) in order to use some cool features like video recording, browser updating, selenium updates etc...
now, I know that in order to use the grid I need to address it via my code and also define the desired capabilities (browser, os etc...).
currently when I'm running the same job twice, my second request will be queued till the first one ends, if I will run the same code from two developers machine it will run at 2 different nodes and the grid can handle both request.

not sure what is wrong with my jenkins configuration or my grid hub configuration, I checked it again and again and all looks good :-)
so guess I'm missing something

any advice/direction/idea will be highly appreciated.

Thanks
Ronen

Comment: When you say that "currently when I'm running the same job twice, my second request will be queued till the first one ends," - is it being queued in jenkins or grid? Same job being queued up in jenkins is a feature.